# Laptop wake up when lid is closed

Tags: suspend, journalctl

I've a problem, every time I close the lid the laptop wakes up 2 seconds after (with the lid still closed)

systemctl suspend/hibernates comes to the same result

The problem happens on every linux distros (Ubuntu, ElementaryOS, debian, ...)

Here is my journalctl when closing the lid

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2018-06-10 12:00:48 CEST. --
juin 10 18:16:26 PierreArch systemd-logind[294]: Lid closed.
juin 10 18:16:26 PierreArch systemd-logind[294]: Suspending...
juin 10 18:16:26 PierreArch systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
juin 10 18:16:26 PierreArch systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
juin 10 18:16:26 PierreArch systemd-sleep[352]: Suspending system...
juin 10 18:16:26 PierreArch kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: OOM killer disabled.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) done.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: ACPI: EC: event blocked
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: ACPI: EC: EC stopped
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: ACPI: Low-level resume complete
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: ACPI: EC: EC started
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel:  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: CPU1 is up
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel:  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: CPU2 is up
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel:  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: CPU3 is up
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: ACPI: button: The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: ACPI: EC: event unblocked
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5690], y [..4772]
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1250..], y [1084..]
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: OOM killer enabled.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Restarting tasks ... 
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: done.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd-rfkill[401]: Failed to open device rfkill0: No such device
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd-sleep[352]: System resumed.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch kernel: PM: suspend exit
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd[1]: sleep.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd[1]: suspend.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
juin 10 18:16:31 PierreArch systemd-logind[294]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
juin 10 18:16:33 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
juin 10 18:16:33 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 2000483 usecs
juin 10 18:16:33 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
juin 10 18:16:33 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 15656 usecs
juin 10 18:16:33 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
juin 10 18:16:33 PierreArch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
juin 10 18:16:36 PierreArch kernel: hp_wmi: Unknown event_id - 131073 - 0x0
juin 10 18:16:38 PierreArch systemd-logind[294]: Lid opened.
```

Hope you can help me, thank you very much in advance

Comment: which distro and wm are you using?

Comment: Hello @vfbsilva, I'm using Arch Linux without any Window Manager (WM). The issue doesn't come from /proc/acpi/wakeup since everything expect power button is disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally find the error, my laptop is an HP Spectre 13 v001nf.
For future users:

You should add this in your rc.local (if you have systemd add this has a service)

```
#!/bin/sh -e
for device in XHC PWRB
do
        if grep -q "$device.*enabled" /proc/acpi/wakeup
        then
                echo $device > /proc/acpi/wakeup
        fi
done
exit 0
```

And voila suspend and hibernate works